# Firebase db integration on flutter for IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, mobile-application

From reading on the firebase website that both realtime database and cloud firestore cannot be written in one code and port to both IOS and android.

Im just making sure that there is no way around this before i start making 2 separate databases and 2 separate projects in order to have it executed on both android and ios.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by "cannot be written in one code and port to both IOS and android"

Comment: Cannot be written in one language, ios(swift, obj-c), android(js)

Comment: i do realize i can do one database just 2 separate projects

Comment: no you write all the logic using just DART but in the integration part which you do only one time is specific to the platform

Comment: Heres what im looking at, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write... this is the integration part you're talking about right, showing from the database?  And if so i would have to write these out throughout my project to get data to show, or are you saying it can all be written in DART?

Comment: please take a look at this [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/) to get a good idea

Comment: Ok im sorry i have a basic understanding of how databases work, so one last question i wouldn't have to create the IPA for ios and the APK for android, until i needed to connect to them remotely/ deploy the app?Sorry and thank you with sticking with me.

Comment: Yes creating the IPA and the APK is the last step